# I can not access a POST within my class in PHP

Tags: php

I have an HTML form with method = "POST" and a submit button. Within my file 'purchases.controller.php', if I do a var_dump ($_POST), you can see all my POST variables belonging to the inputs of the form correctly.

Now, I have another file called 'aux.php' which gets an array by AJAX and then I pass it to a function of a class in the file 'purchases.controller.php'. There, I want to manipulate the array and the POST variables that are arriving, but it only allows me to manipulate the array, the POST within the function do not exist.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**I share the purchases.controller.php code:**

```
//HERE SHOWS ME THE POST VARIABLES AS THE 'registroUsuario', ETC.
var_dump($_POST)

    class Purchases {

        public function ctrCash(&$completeArray){

            //THE ARRAY IS SHOWN CORRECTLY
            var_dump($completeArray);

            if(isset($_POST["registroUsuario"])){

                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["registroUsuario"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})$/', $_POST["registroCalendario"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/', $_POST["registroEmail"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$/', $_POST["registroDireccion"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^[0-9]{7,12}$/', $_POST["registroTelefono"])) {

                 //HERE I WANT TO MANIPULATE EVERYTHING, BUT I CAN NOT SINCE THEY ARE NOT ARRIVING THE POST

    }
```

**And here is the file aux.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['completeArray'])){

include ('purchases.controller.php');

$completeArray = json_decode($_POST['completeArray'], true);

$newPurchase = new Purchase();
$newPurchase -> ctrCash($completeArray);

}
```

Comment: so you've got `$_POST['completeArray']`, but not `$_POST["registroUsuario"]`. Please show the ajax that sends to `aux.php`!

Comment: or: do a `var_dump($_POST)` in aux.php to see what is actually arriving there (through ajax)

Comment: or is `"registroUsuario"` part of the `"completeArray"`??

Comment: @Jeff 'registroUsuario' is not part of 'completeArray'. 'registroUsuario' is part of the HTML form as explained at the beginning of my question. What arrives by ajax to aux.php is an array, which passed by parameter to the function of purchases.controller.php, and it is assumed that it should be able to manipulate both the array (that allows it) and also 'registroUsuario', but the latter does not leave me.

Comment: @Jeff What I do not understand, is why, when doing a var_dump outside of the Purchases class, it allows me to access post variables like "registroUsuario", but when I enter the function of the class, it does not allow it anymore.

Comment: there is no other code than shown in `aux.php` between `include(..);` and `$newPurchase->ctrCash(...)`?

Comment: @Jeff No, I do not have anything else included between the include and $newPurchase->ctrCash(...)